# Retrofit2 Upload image and other data in multipart

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-uploading, multipartform-data

```
ApiServices apiServices = 
RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiServices.class);
MultipartBody.Part body = null;
File file = new File(mFilePath);
RequestBody data = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(“image/*“), file);

body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(“image”, file.getName(), data);
RequestBody description = 
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(“text/plain”),“Hello multipart”);
RequestBody sports_id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(“text/plain”),“2”);
RequestBody location = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(“text/plain”), “New Delhi”);
String auth_token =  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).appSharedPreference.getAuthToken() ;

Call<JsonElement> call = apiservices.postMoment(auth_token , description, sports_id, location, body) ;
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
           Log.e(TAG , “response: “+response.toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.e(TAG , “error: “+t.getMessage());
       }
   });
```

API Interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/moments")
Call<JsonElement> postMoment(
    @Header("X-User-Token")String access_token,
    @Part("description") RequestBody description,
    @Part("sport_id") RequestBody sport_id,
    @Part("location") RequestBody location
    @Part MultipartBody.Part image,

);
```

But, how do I want to ENCAPSULATE all these parameter into one "moment". Such as we do while creating Json Object

```
{
   moment :          
{  “description” : “<Description string>”  , 
    “sports_id”: “<sports_id>” ,
    “location”:   “<location>”
    “image”:”<image>”
}
```

}

My request to api interface should be like:

```
Call<JsonElement> call = apiservices.postMoment(auth_token, single_parameter) ;
```

In that single parameter, all fields to be encapsulate.
I tried Map but couldn't combine whole data into single string called "moment".

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, you can create pojo class for your request

```
@POST("/moments")
Call<JsonElement> postMoment(
    @Header("X-User-Token")String access_token,
    @Body RequestMoment moment,
);
```

interface

```
public class RequestMoment {
    public Moment moment;
    public class Moment {
        public Moment(RequestBody description, RequestBody sport_id, 
                      RequestBody location, MultipartBody.Part image){
            this.description = description;
            this.sport_id = sport_id;
            this.location = location;
            this.image = image;
        }
        public RequestBody description;
        public RequestBody sport_id;
        public RequestBody location;
        public MultipartBody.Part image;
    }
}
```

API call

```
Moment moment = new Moment(description, sports_id, location, body);
Call<JsonElement> call = apiservices.postMoment(auth_token, moment);
```